# Bluetooth LE on Windows Desktop using Qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, bluetooth

I am working on an application using Qt Quick 2.0 for a Windows Desktop environment. I need to communicate with a sensor using Bluetooth LE, for this I have a bluetooth 4.0 usb dongle for my computer.

Since Qt does not support bluetooth on Windows Desktop I'm looking for another API to do this. I've ran into different API's such as 32feet but these kind of API's seem outdated and mostly dont support BLE.

I'm running windows 8.1, so using the Windows bluetooth stack seems like a no-brainer, but I am not sure if it's possible to use this in Qt.

I hope you have an solution or can point me in a direction.

Some more info about my platform:

- Windows 8.1
- BLE usb dongle with Broadcom BCM20702 chip
- Qt Quick 2.0, C++

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For my Windows 8/10 app, I used the native Windows BLE API.  There's nothing that prevents it from being used in Qt, but there's nothing that particularly helps, either.